# what is difference between paypal username password signautre and account clientID and secret

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

what is what is difference between paypal username password signautre and account clientID and secret
I have clientID , Secreat and app display name but unable to find how to get paypal username , password and signature

Comment: SO is more about coding issues and not about how particular api's work.  If this is directly related to coding, then please add the code you are trying to use and any error messages to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The API Username, Password, and Signature are used for the Classic APIs, which were released circa 2001.

The Client ID and Secret are used for the REST APIs, which were released circa 2013.

---

If you need to obtain classic API credentials for an old integration, you can do so via https://www.paypal.com/api